# Toggle all the rows of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have a small problem when I try to toggle the rows of my table it performs for only 1 row. Which I want to happen the same for all the rows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#a").click(function(){
                $('#asd').toggle();
            });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="a">
        <th><td>qw</td></th>

        <tr><td  id="asd">alok</td></tr>
        <tr><td>verma</td></tr>
        </span>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are not toggling any row.. you are toggling a `td` with id `asd`

Comment: what do you really want to do

Comment: This is because you are using one ID you should do $('tr')

Comment: @ArunPJohny I want world peace.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/b827Z/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is toggling only one row because there is only one row in your HTML with the ID asd..
in your code you say `$('#asd')` which means `the element that has ID = asd`

Please see this URL for good reference for building your JQuery selectors: 
https://cdn.tutsplus.com/net/uploads/legacy/154_cheatsheet/jquery12_colorcharge.png
**Please note there is more up-to-date versions of this, but i find this nice for beginner**

try this Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#a").click(function(){
            $('#a tr:not(:first)').toggle();
        });
   });
```

**UPDATE**  (Thanks Rakhi4110)

In this fiddle it shows that first TH in table is actually coming in as a TR..  Think this is JSfiddle specific or browser specific but adding `:not(:first)` to selector will fix that .. I'll update shortly after testing local.. http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/5h9rE/1/

**UPDATE** 
confirmed that this is not JSFiddle/Browser specific.. added `:not(:first)` selector to code example.

Comment: this code removes the entire table when clicked on #a.

Comment: No, it will not remove `<th><td>qw</td></th>` also- it doesnt remove, it toggles. @rakhi4110

Comment: `With no parameters, the .toggle() method simply toggles the visibility of elements:` So it will set all the `<tr>` elements to display none on click ;-)

Comment: @NickR + Rakhi4110 check update, im trying to reproduce locally, i think its a jsfiddle thing.

Comment: yes. i find the th wrapped in tr. Might be jsfiddle specific. Thanks

Comment: Scarily enough @rakhi4110 its not jsfiddle :/ and not browser specific either.. even <thead> will output as <tr>... This is exactly why i Never use tables :) thanks for this anyway though Rakhi